# Unknown Publisher doesn't appear when launching unsigned exe

Tags: windows, installshield, code-signing

If I understand correctly 'The Publisher Could not be verified..' alert appears in Windows7 and XP when you're trying to run digitally unsigned .exe or .msi file.

So, I created installer for my project (I use InstallShield 2012 Limited Edition for this purpose), built it and got Setup.exe. I didn't use any certificate to digitally sign my setup.exe.

May be I missed smth, but I cannot understand why I'm **not getting** Unknown Publisher Security Warning when launching my unsigned setup.exe and trying to install my app on my Win7 box?

Answer (score 0):

The warning is only displayed if the EXE is manifested to request elevation.  If you build it with the AsInvoker setting it won't need to therefore no prompt.

However, assuming it's a Per-Machine install, it'll prompt for elevation when you transition from the InstallUISequence to the InstallExecuteSequence.